# How to add a deselect all button to list of checked inputs that works with script to change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a list of inputs with a button at the bottom that allows you to deselect all elements. Using jquery the inputs modify the class of content on the page. This function works, but i want the deselect all button to be able to deselect all checkboxes AND actually modify the classes. Here is the html:

```
<label class="container">Articles
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="articles" name="articles">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Whitepapers
  <input type="checkbox" id="whitepapers" name="whitepapers" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">News
  <input type="checkbox" id="news" name="news" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Webcasts
  <input type="checkbox" id="webcasts" name="webcasts" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Videos
  <input type="checkbox" id="videos" name="videos" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Case Studies
  <input type="checkbox" id="case-studies" name="case studies" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Blogs
  <input type="checkbox" id="blogs" name="blogs" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container">Data Sheets
  <input type="checkbox" id="data-sheets" name="data sheets" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />
```

Here is the jquery:

```
jQuery('#articles').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-articles').addClass("hide-item").removeClass("force-show-articles");
    } else {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-articles').removeClass("hide-item").addClass("force-show-articles");
    }
});

jQuery('#whitepapers').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-whitepapers').addClass("hide-item").removeClass("force-show-whitepapers");
    } else {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-whitepapers').removeClass("hide-item").addClass("force-show-whitepapers");
    }
});

jQuery('#news').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-news').addClass("hide-item").removeClass("force-show-news");
    } else {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-news').removeClass("hide-item").addClass("force-show-news");
    }
});

jQuery('#webcasts').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-webcasts').addClass("hide-item").removeClass("force-show-webcasts");
    } else {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-webcasts').removeClass("hide-item").addClass("force-show-webcasts");
    }
});

jQuery('#videos').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-videos').addClass("hide-item").removeClass("force-show-videos");
    } else {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-videos').removeClass("hide-item").addClass("force-show-videos");
    }
});

jQuery('#case-studies').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-case-studies').addClass("hide-item").removeClass("force-show-case-studies");
    } else {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-case-studies').removeClass("hide-item").addClass("force-show-case-studies");
    }
});

jQuery('#blogs').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-blogs').addClass("hide-item").removeClass("force-show-blogs");
    } else {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-blogs').removeClass("hide-item").addClass("force-show-blogs");
    }
});

jQuery('#data-sheets').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-data-sheets').addClass("hide-item").removeClass("force-show-data-sheets");
    } else {
        jQuery('.resource-grid .category-data-sheets').removeClass("hide-item").addClass("force-show-data-sheets");
    }
});

// deselect all

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.content-type-selection .check:button').toggle(function(){
        jQuery('.content-type-selection input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        jQuery(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        jQuery('.content-type-selection input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        jQuery(this).val('check all');
    })
})
```

Comment: The html content is wrapped in a div with the class content-type-selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what your saying the problem is; it's that the checkbox's work when you manually select and unselect them as far as the class list being modified but when you use your select/deselect all the checkboxes are checked/unchecked but the class list isn't modified.

This is because your just modifying the attribute of your checkbox inputs on if they should be selected or not, your not `trigger`ing your `change` event on each input that does the class list modifications.

You should be able to simply solve your issue by appending `.trigger('change')` to the end of your `.attr(...)` and `.removeAttr(...)` calls to trigger your existing `change` event that will then detect if the input is checked or not and do the appropriate class list modifications:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.content-type-selection .check:button').toggle(function(){
        jQuery('.content-type-selection input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked').trigger('change');
        jQuery(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        jQuery('.content-type-selection input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').trigger('change');
        jQuery(this).val('check all');
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise and clear explanation. This worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of some help.  You're the first question I've answered in a while as people are usually so quick to try and respond to get points.